# Is it possible mod_sms with mod_callcenter?

Tags: chat, freeswitch

I've set up Freeswitch and simple hotline using `mod_callcenter` and it works fine. I'm curious whether it would be possible to set text-chat hotline by combine `mod_sms` with `mod_callcenter`. Maybe different modules should be used for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this might offer some insights you need to get you going: http://www.thenoccave.com/2012/03/05/freeswitch-callcenter-sms-alerts/

The PHP code that was written is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

$GLOBALS['server'] = 'localhost';
$GLOBALS['port'] = '8021';
$GLOBALS['password'] = 'ClueCon';
$GLOBALS['clickatellapi_id'] = '1234456';
$GLOBALS['clickatelluser'] = 'username';
$GLOBALS['clickatellpassword'] = 'password';
$GLOBALS['contactnumbers'][] = '61123456789';
$GLOBALS['contactnumbers'][] = '61987654321';

$queuealerter = array();

require_once('/usr/local/freeswitch/scripts/ESL.php');

function sendnotification($queuename){

    $message = 'There is a call in the queue ' . $queuename . ' and no agents are logged in to take it';

    for($i=0; $i < count($GLOBALS['contactnumbers']); $i++){

        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=' . $GLOBALS['clickatellapi_id'] . '&user=' . $GLOBALS['clickatelluser'] . '&password=' . $GLOBALS['clickatellpassword'] . '&to=' . $GLOBALS['contactnumbers'][$i] . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
        curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

    }


}

$sock = new ESLconnection($GLOBALS['server'], $GLOBALS['port'], $GLOBALS['password']);

$res = $sock->api('callcenter_config queue list');
$queuelist = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $res->getBody());

//get a list of all the queues
for($i=1; $i < count($queuelist); $i++){

    $queuedetails = explode('|', $queuelist[$i]);
    if($queuedetails[0] != '+OK' && $queuedetails[0] != ''){


        $newQueue = array();
        $newQueue['Name'] = $queuedetails[0];
        $newQueue['AgentCount'] = 0;
        $newQueue['CallCount'] = 0;

        $queuealerter['Queues'][] = $newQueue;

    }
}

//for each queue check if there is a logged in agent
for($i=0; $i < count($queuealerter['Queues']); $i++){

    $res = $sock->api('callcenter_config queue list agents ' . $queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['Name']);
    $agentdetails = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $res->getBody());

    for($i2=1; $i2 < count($agentdetails); $i2++){

        $agentdetail = explode('|', $agentdetails[$i2]);
        if($agentdetail[0] != '+OK' && $agentdetail[0] != '' && $agentdetail[5] == 'Available'){

            $queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['AgentCount'] += 1;

        }
    }

    //get all the calls in the queue

    $res = $sock->api('callcenter_config queue list members ' . $queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['Name']);
    $calldetails = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $res->getBody());

    for($i2=1; $i2 < count($calldetails); $i2++){

        $calldetail = explode('|', $calldetails[$i2]);
        if($calldetail[0] != '+OK' && $calldetail[0] != ''){

            $queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['CallCount'] += 1;

        }
    }


}

//for each queue check
for($i=0; $i < count ($queuealerter['Queues']); $i++){

    if($queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['CallCount'] > 0 && $queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['AgentCount'] == 0){
        sendnotification($queuealerter['Queues'][$i]['Name']);
    }

}

?>
```